# How to use word_rsplit

Tags: isabelle

There is a function called `word_rsplit` in `~~/src/HOL/Word/Word.thy`.

```
definition word_rsplit :: "'a :: len0 word => 'b :: len word list" where
  "word_rsplit w = 
  map word_of_int (bin_rsplit (len_of TYPE ('b)) (len_of TYPE ('a), uint w))"
```

I want to split a `32 word` to four `8 word`, this function seems to be perfect.

And lemma `word_rcat (word_rsplit w) = w` is useful for me too.

So I need to know how to use `word_rsplit`, how to specify `'a` = 32 and `'b` = 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a variant of `word_rsplit` for specific word types, you can just give explicit type constraints. E.g., your example where you want to split a `32 word` into several `8 word`s, could be specified as follows:

```
word_rsplit :: 32 word => 8 word list"
```

**Example:**

```
value "(word_rsplit :: 32 word ⇒ 8 word list) 1024"
```

produces

```
"[0, 0, 4, 0]"
  :: "8 word list"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems so reasonable now.